# If statement in Python always return true

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program which will ask my name and password before giving me access. Somehow I am not writing it right

```
print("Enter your name:")
myName = input ()

if myName == "Akib":
    print("Enter your password")

password = input()
password = "toma"

if password == "toma":
    print("Access granted")
else:
    print("Not granted")
```

Comment: inout was a spelling mistake when i copied here

Comment: What errors do you get when you run this code?  What have you tried doing so far to fix them?

Comment: After `password = input()` you are setting the same variable `password` as `password = "toma" ` which is likely the problem.

Comment: Thanks for joining SO. Please, explain the question in the body and not in the title.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you set `password` to the input and then rest `password` by setting it to `toma` so you need to remove `password = "toma"`.

```
print("Enter your name:")
myName = input ()

if myName == "Akib":
    print("Enter your password")

password = input()

if password == "toma":
    print("Access granted")
else:
    print("Not granted")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password = "password"  # store your password here
name = "name"  # store your name here

input_name = str(input("> enter your name: "))
input_password = str(input("> enter your password: "))

if input_name == name and input_password == password:
    print("access granted !")
else:
    print("declined !")
```

> It can be done like-so. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired function like so!

In this case, if the name entered is not 'Akib', it would not even prompt the user to enter the password.

```
# prompt for name
myName = input("Enter your name: ")

# check if name is correct
if myName == "Akib":

    # prompt for password
    password = input("Enter your password: ")

    # check if password is correct
    if password == "toma":
        print("Access granted")
    else:
        print("Not granted")

else:
    print("Not granted")
```